# How can I change resolution in LXDE?

Tags: lxde

I installed yesterday the 14.04 distribution of Lubuntu and the default resolution is very low.

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm 
    1366x768 59.8*+ 
    1360x768 60.0 
    1280x720 60.0 
    1024x768 75.1 70.1 60.0 
    832x624 74.6 
    800x600 72.2 75.0 60.3 56.2 
    640x480 75.0 72.8 66.7 60.0 
    720x400 70.1      
    640x400 70.0 
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: This probably has very little to do with LXDE as compared with having to do with your video card driver and your Xorg configuration.

Comment: @HalosGhost I don't think so, because before I had lubuntu 12.04 with the resolution I want. And the only thing of hardward I have changed is the hard disk.

Comment: @HalosGhost Oh, I had understand the comment in a wrong way, sorry. How can I change that?

Comment: Cut n' paste the output of `xrandr` in.  You may have to install a small package (probably called "xrandr") if the command is not found.

Comment: Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
   640x400        70.0  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: So it is at `1366 x 768` -- does it appear lower? Or do you think it should be able to go higher than that?  It's about right for, e.g., a 14" laptop, but there may be some lxde related configuration that makes the GUI look wrong.

Comment: Stop using the screen tag, is meant for GNU Screen. Read the [tag wiki for more info.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/screen/info)

Comment: @goldilocks Yes, it does appear quite lower than that.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use lxrandr -- if it didn't install automatically, go to a terminal and install it:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install lxrandr
```

Once it's installed, in Lubuntu you will find it under

Preferences --> Monitor Settings

Comment: This is what I use as well and it is very easy to manage screen resolution. Use the advanced settings.